# C expression must be a modifiable lvalue (Why am i getting on this expression)

Tags: c, if-statement

I have this expression with ?: operator:

```
(adc.Voltage1[Counter.ADC_ConversionCount] = ADC_readResult(Handler.myAdc, ADC_ResultNumber_1))  > 10 ? Counter.WriteOut = 1 : Counter.WriteOut = 0;
```

And the same expression with if-else:

```
if((adc.Voltage1[Counter.ADC_ConversionCount] = ADC_readResult(Handler.myAdc, ADC_ResultNumber_1)) > 10 ){
    Counter.WriteOut = 1;
}else{
    Counter.WriteOut = 0;
}
```

Why am I getting "expression must be a modifiable lvalue" error in the first case?

The ADC_readResult function return type is uint_least16_t. Here is the Counter struct definition and the ADC struct definition:

```
typedef struct __COUNTERS__ {
    uint16_t WriteOut;
    uint16_t ADC_ConversionCount;
    uint16_t ADC_CycleCount;
    uint8_t LimitADCReached1;
    uint8_t LimitADCReached2;
    uint8_t LimitADCReached3;
    uint8_t LimitADCReached4;
    uint8_t LimitADCReached5;
} COUNTERS;

typedef struct __ADC_VOLTAGES__ {
    uint16_t Voltage1[ADC_VAL];
    uint16_t Voltage2[ADC_VAL];
    uint16_t Voltage3[ADC_VAL];
    uint16_t Voltage4[ADC_VAL];
    uint16_t Voltage5[ADC_VAL];

} ADC;
```

Comment: Even if it compiles, writing such a complicated and unreadable expression is BAD PRACTICE.

Comment: Just because you can write a whole C program in one line, doesn't mean that you get to abuse it. Your line is horrible! Code that is easy to read and interpret is more maintainable than code where the author thinks he/she's very clever for cramming many things in one line.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error you're getting has to do with the way the expression is parsed.

Your expression (simplified) looks like this:

```
(a = b) < 10 ? c = 1 : c = 0
```

The ternary operator `?:` has higher precedence than the assignment operator `=`.  While the inner `=` is seen as part of the ternary, the rightmost one is not.  So the expression parses like this:

```
((a = b) < 10 ? c = 1 : c) = 0;
```

The result is that you're trying to assign the value 0 to an expression that is not an lvalue, i.e. a variable name or a dereferenced pointer.  You would need parenthesis for it to parse the way you want:

```
((a = b) < 10) ? (c = 1) : (c = 0);
```

Since what you're doing is assigning a value to `c` based on an expression, it can be simplified as follows:

```
c = ((a = b) < 10) ?  1 : 0;
```

Or even:

```
c = ((a = b) < 10);
```

Translating back to your code:

```
Counter.WriteOut = (adc.Voltage1[Counter.ADC_ConversionCount] = ADC_readResult(Handler.myAdc, ADC_ResultNumber_1) > 10);
```

And made more readable by splitting the operations:

```
adc.Voltage1[Counter.ADC_ConversionCount] = ADC_readResult(Handler.myAdc, ADC_ResultNumber_1);
Counter.WriteOut = (adc.Voltage1[Counter.ADC_ConversionCount] > 10);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think it should be:

```
Counter.WriteOut = (adc.Voltage1[Counter.ADC_ConversionCount] = ADC_readResult(Handler.myAdc, ADC_ResultNumber_1)) > 10 ? 1 : 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

The `?:` operator has higher precedence than `=` operator, so the first expression is interpreted as

```
(
  (adc.Voltage1[Counter.ADC_ConversionCount] = ADC_readResult(Handler.myAdc, ADC_ResultNumber_1))  > 10 ?
    Counter.WriteOut = 1 : Counter.WriteOut
) = 0
```

Therefore, the lefthand expression of `=` is not modifiable.

Use parenthesis to avoid this:

```
(adc.Voltage1[Counter.ADC_ConversionCount] = ADC_readResult(Handler.myAdc, ADC_ResultNumber_1))  > 10 ? Counter.WriteOut = 1 : (Counter.WriteOut = 0);
```

(no parenthesis are needed for `Counter.WriteOut = 1` because it is middle of `?:` operator and no ambiguity is there)

Because what is assigned are common `Counter.WriteOut`, I prefer

```
Coumter.WriteOut = ((adc.Voltage1[Counter.ADC_ConversionCount] = ADC_readResult(Handler.myAdc, ADC_ResultNumber_1)) > 10 ? 1 : 0);
```

or, using definition of comparision operators of C (it returns 1 for true and 0 for false),

```
Coumter.WriteOut = ((adc.Voltage1[Counter.ADC_ConversionCount] = ADC_readResult(Handler.myAdc, ADC_ResultNumber_1)) > 10);
```